# Metrizability of the set of probability measures with the Kantorovich–Rubinstein metric

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, weak-topology, metrizability

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and let $\mathcal{M}(X)$ be the set of probability measures. Then the weak topology on $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is metrizable, for example with the Wasserstein-metric and with the Prokhorov-metric, which seem to be the most famous ones. But both metrics seem kind of unhandy to me. Now I read something about a third metric, the Kantorovich–Rubinstein metric, which should be compatible to the weak topology, too. It is defined by

$$\mathrm{d}(\mu,\nu)=\sup\left\{\left|\int f\mathrm{d}\mu-\int f\mathrm{d}\nu\right|,~f\in\mathrm{Lip}_1(X,\mathbb{R}),~\sup_{x\in X}f(x)\leq 1\right\},$$

and I'm wondering if there is an easy way to show that it indeed metrizes the weak topology. Especially I can't figure out, why an open ball wrt. this metric, which should be defined as

$$B_\epsilon(\bar{\mu})=\left\{\mu\in\mathcal{M}(X):\left|\int f\mathrm{d}\mu-\int f\mathrm{d}\bar{\mu}\right|<\epsilon~\forall f\in\mathrm{Lip}_1(X,\mathbb{R}),~\sup_{x\in X}f(x)\leq 1\right\},$$

is indeed open in the weak topology. $\mathrm{Lip}_1(X,\mathbb{R})$ should be separabel but I don't know how this can help. Do you have any hints for me how one can prove that?

Comment: Kantorovich-Rubenstein is the same as the Wasserstein metric (at least for compact metric spaces). It's writing the dual of the linear program that defines the latter.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add a reference - the result is called the 'Kantorovich-Rubinstein Duality Theorem'. Searching for this should give you plenty to read. Also, at least for finite metric spaces you should be able to directly show this via LP duality, which may be a useful exercise.

Comment: Thank you! I have now read over some articles about the Kantorovich-Rubinstein Duality Theorem and so far I did not understand so much. That seems to be way beyond my knowledge. I suppose there is no "easy" way to show the metrizability directly? And do you know a good reference, where the Kantorovich-Rubinstein Duality Theorem is proven? The articles I found were quite general.

Comment: Ah, TBH, it's been some time since I've studied this, I'm sure I've forgotten most of the stuff. But I remember a standard theorem that says a sequence $\mu_n$ weakly converges to $\mu$ if and only if for all bounded Lipschitz functions $f,$ $\int f \,\mathrm{d}\mu_n \to \int f \,\mathrm{d}\mu$. Can't you use this to argue that $d$ induces the weak topology? As for references, well, I'd maybe look for some textbook on optimal transport. There's been a slew of them recently, but I can't really attest to quality.

Comment: I would need to argue, that $\int f\mathrm{d}\mu_n\to\int f\mathrm{d}\mu$ for every $f\in\mathrm{Lip}_1$ implies that $\sup_{f\in\mathrm{Lip}_1}\left|\int f\mathrm{d}\mu_n-\int f\mathrm{d}\mu\right|\to 0$. That would be easy to show if the set of Lipschitz-continuous functions would be finite but thats of course not the case. And even if I restrict to a countable dense set I have no idea how I can pass from the convergence for every function to the convergence of the supremum. Maybe there is some general result which states, that something converges for every $f$ iff the supremum converges?

Comment: I believe there is an error in the definition of the Kantorovich-Rubinstein formula - there should be no constraint on the supremum of f. Otherwise the distance between two Dirac deltas can never exceed 2. The actual Wasserstein metric is such that the distance between Dirac deltas is equal to the distance between their supports (which are just points in X). See:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric#Dual_representation_of_W1